# Acumos onboarding errors when onboarding a Python model

Tags: acumos

I followed the example here: https://pypi.org/project/acumos in order to onboard a (very simple) Python model to Acumos. When I try to onboard the model as a normal user (with MLP System User or Publiser role) I get some sort of authentication error. If I try to onboard the model as an Admin user the model seems to be onboarded but with errors (see image). I have three questions:

1. Is it only Admin users that are allowed to onboard models?
2. How the h... (pardon the language :-)) do I find out what the errors are?
3. How can I delete an onboarded model?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to onboard now. I switched to an Ubuntu 18.04 VM and generated the model there and it is now working. My first attempt was on a Macbook Pro and it looks like that something is wrong with the generation of the model on the Mac. I will try to investigate further what the difference in the generated models are and may post an update if I find something worth sharing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Every registered user can on-board a model, definitely not limited to admin.
2. In the on-boarding screen with the icons that blink, on error a message should be shown by the icon for the step that failed.
3. I believe the portal-marketplace version 1.16.2 (early Athena release) does not permit deletion of a failed model.  That feature was added slightly later.

Re #1, how did you on-board, from a Python command line using the Acumos library or from the portal on-boarding-by-web page?

Comment: Re #1, I tried using: a) session.push() in the Python model code, b) using the onboard-model.sh script with host, user, passwd, the model folder created by session.dump() and insecure parameters c) using the web onboarding (with the three files resulting after session.dump() in the Python model file zipped into an archive file). The only way that kind of worked was web onboarding but the result was the error described here in the original post. By the way, ref #2: there is no icon that blinks but I noticed now that if I hoover over the first icon I see "Invalid JSON".

Answer (score 0):

I can also probably help you since I wrote the onboard_model.sh script and the AIO (oneclick_deploy.sh) toolset. The CLI-based onboarding should be pretty reliable (I use it a lot in platform testing), but there are various ways it can break, that we are working to improve upon.

First is that it may take 10 minutes or more to build the microservice, and the onboarding push request will stay open during that time, and may time out indicating that there was an error, when there really wasn't. If you check the "My Models" and you see the model icon with an "error found" overlay you will know it did fail for some reason.

If you see "error found" you will not be able to review the artifacts/logs from the Portal. That, and the delay in onboarding, are being worked on now and should be resolved in this release.

To see what really happened and send us info that we can help to debug this further, you will need to provide the logs from the onboarding and microservice-generation components. To do that, we need to know:

- How was the Acumos platform you are working with deployed, e.g. using the AIO (oneclick_deploy.sh) or some other method.
- If you did use the AIO tools, when did you clone the repo (so we know what version you used). Later commits are more reliable generally, though the toolset is in continual evolution.
- Was the platform deployed under kubernetes or docker?

Comment: I have managed to onboard now. I switched to an Ubuntu 18.04 VM and generated the model there and it is now working. My first attempt was on a Macbook Pro and it looks like that something is wrong with the generation of the model on the Mac.

Comment: Great, glad it's working. Note that we have probably not been clear on what client environments have been tested and verified. I'll give that feedback to the test team.